# Is Google Chrome, 32 bit only?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, 64-bit

when I checked my Task Manager -> Processes .. I noticed that Google Chrome is running as a 32bit application.

ie. `chrome.exe *32`

is there a way to make it 64 bit?

OS: Windows 7 x64 Bit.

Comment: You cannot make any 32-bit programs to be 64 bits unless you compile from source. An app doesn't have 64-bit version simply because the developers don't want to compiler for 64-bit target

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Chrome 64-bit is now available.

https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/?platform=win64

Comment: WOOT WOOT @sathya! would that mean we we need to uninstall or re-install our chrome installed version when it goes stable?

Comment: I do believe you'll need to reinstall, but with Chrome sync, that shouldn't be a problem.. @Pure.Krome

Comment: awesome! and yep. :heart: Chrome sync :)

Comment: Chrome x64 available now: https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/?platform=win64

Comment: if there are changes, please add it as a separate section, don't make such big changes like that

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc what do you mean?

Comment: Did you open your edit history and see how much you have changed the answer? No one would click the history link and don't know why your answer was accepted. On stackexchange such radical changes are not allowed and would be rollback

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc they aren't allowed on other people's answers. I'm at the liberty to update my answer as things change. That's been the policy on [se] since the past 5 years that I've been around

Answer (score 3):

On Windows, no, there currently is no 64-bit build. Linux is a [different story](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxBuild64Bit), however.

Answer (score 3):

There is [not yet a 64-bit version](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/64-bit-support) of either Google Chrome or Chromium available for Windows (though it does include 64-bit versions of a [few of the components](http://www.chromium.org/nativeclient/design-documents/native-client-in-chrome-on-64-bit-windows)). There is however [work being done](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=8606&q=windows%2064%20bit&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Pri%20Area%20Feature%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Modified%20Owner%20Mstone%20OS) to provide one and you can star it to keep up on the progress.